# Save Future Occurrences W.R.T event_id

Tags: python, django

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    time_modified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(_('start time'))
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(_('end time'))
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name=_('event'), editable=False)
    lead_technician = models.ForeignKey('mbi.Employee', related_name='tasks_lead')
    team = models.ManyToManyField('mbi.Employee', related_name='assigned_tasks', blank=True)
    vehicles = models.ManyToManyField('vehicles.Vehicle', related_name='assigned_tasks', blank=True)
```

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditOccurrenceForm(request.POST, occurrence=occurrence, user=request.user, save_all=True,changed_data=False)
        formset = file_formset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=occurrence)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            occurrence = form.save()
```

Now below part i have done to achieve update future occurrences so, if user clicks on "Save All" button then

1. Get all occurrences with same event.
2. Then in loop i am submitting form with instance of occurrence which is "o" in the loop.

Now but problem is, all field are updating of future occurrences.

```
            if request.POST.get('save_all'):
                occurrences = Occurrence.objects.filter(event=occurrence.event) \
                                      .filter(start_time__gt=occurrence.start_time)
                if occurrences:
                    for o in occurrences:
                        form = EditOccurrenceForm(request.POST, occurrence=o, user=request.user, save_all=True)
                        if form.is_valid():
                            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(occurrence_detail, kwargs={'occurrence_id': occurrence.id}))
```

---

This is my Occurrence Model and the requirement is: When user changes any/Specific field while submitting form, then Future Occurrence W.R.T to event_id should be updated as well.

For example if an event has three Occurrences and from first occurrence user tries to change "team" and "vehicles" then only "vehicles and "team" should be changed in all other future occurrences.

Now I figured out one part which is getting future Occurrence but not Occurrences from the Past. But when changing the future Occurrences it's updating all occurrences all data, which is not required.

I hope I made myself clear while explaining.

Comment: This is a lot of code and you haven't told us what the current problem is with your code. You should explain which part of the code you wrote to do the specific behavior you're describing and what exactly isn't working as expected. Note that you should be using a `ModelForm` instead of a `Form`, it would simplify your code a lot (as you can initialise with an instance instead of having to manually assign all kinds of fields to `self.occurence`).

Comment: Also try to simplify the problem, show the **minimum required code to reproduce the issue**. Another tip: Use your debugger. Set a breakpoint in your view/form's save() method and step through your code line by line, inspecting the variables to see if everything behaves as expected.

Comment: You should still show us the main skeleton of your form, since that's how you actually save the future occurrences. I saw it already, so I wrote the answer below, but it's important for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it this way:

- You need to keep track of the data that was changed. Since you're changing an existing `Occurrence`, you should change your form to a `ModelForm` (you're not showing your form but the way you initialise it indicates it's a `Form`). That way, `form.changed_data` will tell you what was changed with respect to the initial `Occurrence` instance (`form.instance`). Otherwise, you'll have to write an equivalent `changed_data` method yourself, because the `Form`'s `changed_data` will always give you that everything was changed since it compares to `initial`.
- After you've save the changed `Occurrence`, you'll need to write a method that only saves the changed fields for the future occurrences. I would **not** reinitialise the form with the future instances to do that, as that leads to all fields being assigned the `request.POST` values. Write a new method on your form, (e.g. `save_changed_data_to_occurence(self, occurrence)`) that does that:

```
def save_changed_data_to_occurrence(self, occurrence):
    changed = False
    for field in self.changed_data:
        model_fields = [f.name for f in occurrence._meta.get_fields()]
        if field in model_fields:
            changed = True
            if field not in ['team', 'vehicles']:
                setattr(occurrence, field, self.cleaned_data[field])
            else:
                # ManyToMany relationship, use `set()`
                getattr(occurrence, field).set(self.cleaned_data[field])
    if changed:
        occurrence.save()
```

- In your view, you just call `form.save_changed_data_to_occurrence(o)` for each occurrence in the future for the same `event`.